# JTable not populating correct information

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

i am populating my table from a tree map and the tree map is being populated from my sql database, the error is the order in which the data is appearing in my table.
i have posted a screenshot for you to see.

[image]

and here is the image from my sql

[image]

```
public class LibraryData {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet res;

    public LibraryData() {
        try {

            // con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://;localhost:3306")
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQL-SERVER;" + "databaseName=oe323;integratedSecurity=true;";
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + ex);

        }
    }

    public String listAll1() {
        String output = "";
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LibraryTable");

            while (res.next()) { // there is a result
                // the name field is the thrid one in the ResultSet
                // Note that with  ResultSet we count the fields starting from 1
                output += res.getString(1) + " " + res.getString(2) + " - "
                        + res.getString(3) + " " + res.getString(4) + " "
                        + res.getString(5) + "\n";
                System.out.println(output);
                library.put("" + res.getInt(1), new Item(res.getString(2), res.getString(3), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(4))));



            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static class Item {

        Item(String n, String a, int r) {
            name = n;
            artist = a;
            rating = r;
        }
        // instance variables 
        private String name;
        private String artist;
        private int rating;
        private int playCount;

        public String toString() {
            return name + " - " + artist;
        }
    }
    private static Map<String, Item> library = new TreeMap<String, Item>();
//

    static {

    }

    public static String listAll() {
        String output = "";
        Iterator iterator = library.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            Item item = library.get(key);
            output += key + " " + item.name + " - " + item.artist + "\n";


        }
        return output;
    }

    public static void fillTable() {
        Iterator iterator = LibraryData.library.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            LibraryData.Item item = LibraryData.library.get(key);

            DeleteSong.data = new Object[1][3];

            DeleteSong.data[0][0] = key;
            DeleteSong.data[0][1] = item.artist;

            DeleteSong.data[0][2] = item.name;
            DeleteSong.modeltable.addRow(DeleteSong.data[0]);


        }

    }

    public static void fillTable1() {
        // listAll1();
        Iterator iterator = LibraryData.library.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            LibraryData.Item item = LibraryData.library.get(key);

            CheckLibrary.data = new Object[1][4];

            CheckLibrary.data[0][0] = key;
            CheckLibrary.data[0][1] = item.artist;

            CheckLibrary.data[0][2] = item.name;
            CheckLibrary.modeltable.addRow(CheckLibrary.data[0]);

            CheckLibrary.data[0][3] = item.rating;
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the Artist name in table also ? And all the other columns are displayed in wrong place. How about some showing some code

Comment: just realised that artist and track name were the wrong way round, specifically what part of the code would you like to see

Comment: Pertinent code, code that shows us your bug.

Comment: When i run the program i am not getting any bug(errors), as you can see from the images the Jtable no starts at 1 and skips to 10 and when it reaches 19 goes to 2..20..21..22 etc

Comment: The code where you are "populating the table from a tree map and the tree map is being populated from the sql database". That code would be nice to see

Comment: As I can see in the console, the output data is correct. I suspect the problem is in the fillTable() and fillTable1() functions

Comment: @Andrei The problem is that he is converting his integer ID's to strings before storing in `library`, then using strings as the sort key; and so the ordering from the `TreeMap<String,...>` is lexicographical instead of numerical. Notice that the SQL query shows 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but the screenshot of the application shows 1, 10, 11, 12, 13.

Comment: `"When i run the program i am not getting any bug(errors)..."` -- you need to understand that this statement isn't true. Yes, you're not getting any **exceptions**, and your code compiles, but since it is misbehaving, you have a **logic** bug in your code, and your need here is to post the code that likely has that logic bug. Make sense? I see that Jason has your answer, but in the future for similar questions, you will want to try to isolate the code that holds the logic behind whatever misbehavior you're seeing.

Comment: Hello. I see that you have another question and have changed your original question. I'm going to ask you not to do this, since by doing this, you have invalidated Jason's answer. Instead, you've accepted his solution, let's roll back your question to the original state (I will do this for you), and why not ask your new question as a completely new question to this site. Sure link to the old question if it refers to information that it holds, but let's not change the old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your keys are actually numbers, and you are expecting to sort them in numerical order, but your `library` keys are `String`s, which are sorted in lexicographical  order, which is, e.g. *1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, ...* (just like *a, aa, ab, ac, ad, b, ba, bb, bc, ...*). This ordering is apparent in your screen shots.

This is because, for some reason, you've decided to convert your integer keys to strings when placing in the library map:

```
private static Map<String, Item> library = new TreeMap<String, Item>();
... 
// in listAll1() and elsewhere:
library.put("" + res.getInt(1), ...
```

You should use data types that are appropriate for the information you are storing. If your keys are integers, use integers, e.g.:

```
private static Map<Integer, Item> library = new TreeMap<Integer, Item>();
...
// in listAll1() and elsewhere:
library.put(res.getInt(1), ...
```

You had a screen shot that showed this but no code. Then you added the code but removed the screen shot. I added the screen shot back in to your question. In the future, please try and post code and information that is directly relevant to the problem you are seeing.

Comment: i have taken note of what you have said but in my case i am using string and integer values

Comment: @Reynolds No, you're using a `String` as your key in `library`. And you're explicitly converting your integer to a string when you store it there. A `TreeMap` key set is iterated in the natural order of the keys. The natural order of `String`s is alphabetical. It does not matter that your strings contain digit characters 0-9 instead of letters. A number inside a string is still a string. Use the correct data type. Use an `Integer` for your map key type. The natural sort order of an `Integer` is in numerical order. Then the `keySet()` iteration will be done in proper numerical order.

Comment: An alternative, if you insist on strings, is to pad the key strings to a fixed length by prepending leading 0's to the strings when you do the integer -> string conversion. "002" will sort before "019". Just make sure you prepend enough leading 0's to cover the entire range of valid IDs. Still, I recommend using data types that accurately represent the information.

Comment: i'm going to use your advice and change the data types to integer, once i've tweaked it i'll let you know what happens, thanks.

Comment: hi, so after a break went back to it, changed the data type from string to integer and after tweaking couple other things, the program functions perfectly. Thanks

Comment: (not suggested, but) Map isn't good underlaying array for JTable, Map hasn't indexing, convert view to model doesn't works from sorted or filtered JTables view, util.List is better choice, @Reynolds JTable and table in database has similair structure,

Comment: @mKorbel Sort of, but you are coupling data and GUI too closely. Map is a good underlying structure if the data is represented by a map. Lists are a good underlying structure if the data is represented by a list. Let the data itself determine the underlying structure, without consideration of the GUI. Then, an appropriate table model that can handle the data can be built on top of that, and can take care of the details of how to *display* a useful representation of the data in tabular form. If it turns out a table cannot accurately represent the data, then a table may not be appropriate.

Comment: (i.e. if the GUI can't represent the data, change the GUI, not the data; if the data belongs in a map then it belongs in a map, the table is one possible *view* of that data)

Comment: @Jason C you can't use Map for JTree/JTable, agree (if isn't there JTree/JTable) with, good described idea, (last comment, disagree, not never :-) and another blablabalbla, I'm think, sure table from database == Vector<Vector>)

Comment: @mKorbel You can "use" a map for a `JTable`. The OP is doing it. As for the database; same deal on that end. The database is just a serialization format. The data itself is (presumably) represented by a map, regardless of whether or not it came from a database, a file, user input, an algorithm etc. (By the way, database tables represent maps quite well, consider the trivial example of a unique primary key.) :)

Comment: @mKorbel Check this out for example http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/MapTableModel.htm. A little outdated, but it's a good example of using the table model as simply a view of data in a map.

Comment: yes Map is database structure from assembler, cobol but we are there behid one wall, bridge called JDBC, I leaving any comments here, look around search for (due to respect to you, you are very good poster here) every posts about Hash/Map v.s JTree/Jtable are switched to util.List for AbstractTableModel, Vector for DefaultTableModel, again you can get (f.i.) 1st. or last row to models index from sorted or filtered JTables view, Hash/Map hasn't internal index,